# How to center a Responsive CSS Table

Tags: css, css-tables, centering

I'm converting PHP, HTML, CSS site with a number of traditional html tables to Responsive Tables using CSS.
The question: How can I get this table to center on the page?
Maybe this has to do with using Display: Block and then seperatly defining the column widths... but I've experimented & researched/Googled for hours and can't get a combination that maintains individual column widths while centering the entire css table... so any help is appreciated.
Example code of what I've tried is below

```css
.rTable {
   display: block;
}
.rTableRow{
   clear: both;
}
.rTableCell {
   border: 1px solid #999999;
   float: left;
   height: 17px;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding: 3px 1.8%;
}
.column1{ width: 10%;}
.column2{ width: 20%;}
.column3{ width: 30%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="rTable">
 <div class="rTableRow">
  <div class="rTableCell column1"><style="width: 200px;">ID</style></div>
  <div class="rTableCell column2">Name</div>
  <div class="rTableCell column3">City</div>
 </div>
 <div class="rTableRow">
  <div class="rTableCell column1">9</div>
  <div class="rTableCell column2">Bobby McGee</div>
  <div class="rTableCell column3">Baton Rouge</div>
 </div>
 <div class="rTableRow">
  <div class="rTableCell column1">61</div>
  <div class="rTableCell column2">Big Bad John</div>
  <div class="rTableCell column3">Lumberton</div>
 </div>
  <div class="rTableRow">
  <div class="rTableCell column1">967</div>
  <div class="rTableCell column2">Bjilly Joe McAllister</div>
  <div class="rTableCell column3">Tallahatchie</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can do this in better way using a grid, are you ok with that?

Comment: pssst.. There's nothing wrong with using table tags for actual tables. Divs should only be used as a last resort when nothing else fits the purpose.

Comment: Gee, somehow I missed CSS grids. Just looked it up. I'll give it a try. Thanks for the tip. That said, I thought old fashioned tables were not "responsive" so should be ditched in today's world of multiple platforms including tablets and smart phones.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using some display flex like this:

```css
    .container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    /*centers the table horizontally */
    justify-content: center;
    /*centers the table vertically */
    align-items: center;
}

.rTable {
    display: block;
}

.rTableRow {
    clear: both;
}

.rTableCell {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    float: left;
    height: 17px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px 1.8%;
}

.column1 {
    width: 10%;
}

.column2 {
    width: 20%;
}

.column3 {
    width: 30%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="rTable">
        <div class="rTableRow">
            <div class="rTableCell column1">
                <style
                ="width: 200px;">ID</style></div>
            <div class="rTableCell column2">Name</div>
            <div class="rTableCell column3">City</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableRow">
            <div class="rTableCell column1">9</div>
            <div class="rTableCell column2">Bobby McGee</div>
            <div class="rTableCell column3">Baton Rouge</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableRow">
            <div class="rTableCell column1">61</div>
            <div class="rTableCell column2">Big Bad John</div>
            <div class="rTableCell column3">Lumberton</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableRow">
            <div class="rTableCell column1">967</div>
            <div class="rTableCell column2">Bjilly Joe McAllister</div>
            <div class="rTableCell column3">Tallahatchie</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to do it so thanks. However it does not honor the column widths specified. That said it does maintain uniform column widths. I'll experiment with actual cases which have more columns.
The issue with this is having to create a class for every column in the entire website... If you have 20 tables... which are actually displaying query results... and each table has n columns... then it would seem to require 20 * n column width classes.
Maybe I'll start another thread about how to maintain uniform column widths when displaying query results in a table view.

Answer (score 0):

You can (for example) do this:

```
.rTable {
   display: block;
   padding:0 3em;
   width: calc(100% - 6em);
}
```

Comment: padding seems to shift table to the left but not center in the screen